# Whats wrong with my output answer?

Tags: c, helper

Hi guys this is my first question so I’m hoping to get some help.
Basically the Output is Wrong though the calculation is right!!
Whenever I add more than 7 variables to 'total' the output get corrupted
7 and less variables the output give a right answer??!!
This is my coding I need Your HELP Guyz

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float total = 0, necklace, scarf, cotton, Lace, Hijab, h, m, l, z;
    int ch, q;
    printf("\nFashion : \n1.Fashion Necklace <Price=RM29>\n2.Scarf <Price=RM25>\n3.Cotton T-shirts <Price=RM35>\n4.Lace Blazer <price=RM33>\n5.Set of 2 Hijab <price=RM35>\n6.Fleece-Lined Hoodie <price=RM49>");
    printf("\nEnter Your Choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if (ch < 10)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Quantity : ");
        scanf("%d", &q);
        if (ch == 1)
        {
            necklace = 29 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 2)
        {
            scarf = q * 25;
        }
        else if(ch == 3)
        {
            cotton = 35 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 4)
        {
            Lace = 33 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 5)
        {
            Hijab = 35 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 6)
        {
            h = 49 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 7)
        {
            m = 20 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 8)
        {
            l = 40 * q;
        }
        else if(ch == 9)
        {
            z = 15 * q;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Choice!!!");
    }
    total = (scarf + necklace + cotton + Lace + Hijab + h + m + l + z);
    printf("\nTotal = RM%.2f", total);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of using a big `if ... else if ...` chain, you might want to look into using the `switch` statement.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Or an array to map `ch` onto those constants (`total += val_map[ch-1]*q` and the like)

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) use meaningful variable names.  variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains lots of 'magic numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using #define statements or enum statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code has a logic problem. 1) most of the variables are not being set/initialized on any one pass through the code.  2) when an invalid value is entered, the code goes ahead and sums the numbers and prints the resulting value.

Comment: unless your running with no OS, all the signatures for the `main()` function have a `int` return type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not initialize all those variables, which means their value will be *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior*.

If you initialize all those variables to zero it should work.

The reason you get the wrong value is because of the above, *and* you only set one variable in the program, adding it to all the uninitialized variables. So in practice what's happening is that you add a lot of seemingly random values to a single calculated value and print that as output.

Answer (score 0):

you have t initialize your values it is a grat habit in coding espicialy when you use it in summing . for example :

int = x ,y ; // you did not initialaize so x and y have a random number 
int sum = x+y; //will give you a wrong answer since the compiler doesnt give them zero without you tell him to do that .

---

int = x =5 ,y = 0;
int sum = x+y; //leads to 5 .

Answer (score 0):

non-initialized variables will return whatever in the allocated memory location, it will be a garbage.
you have to initialize all the used variables .
please consider below code.

```
int a,b;
a=5;
printf("\na= %d b= %d",a,b);
```

it is guaranteed that a will return 5 but nobody knows what b will return.
as you cant know what is stored on the memory reserved for variable b.